# Access the GeoServer remotely

Tags: geoserver

I have installed GeoServer 2.14.1 on server 92.20.100.12 at port 8080. Now I want to access that GeoServer from my computer like that

```
http://92.20.100.12:8080/geoserver
```

I added new "Inbound Rule" for port 8080 but I could not access GeoServer.
What do I need to change?

Operation system that GeoServer installed: Windows Server 2016

Comment: Please edit the question to add details about the environment: What operating system? What service provider? What client? It's quite possible there's a firewall you cannot control blocking port 8080 traffic, in which case this may be impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BeaR said, GeoServer needs to be started as a console/service. See if you can ping the machine where GeoServer is installed using ping command from your machine with the same IP as you mentioned. Sometimes machine name is better due to IP can change.

Also sometimes 8080 may be used any other app server such as Tomcat. That can cause conflict. In that case, you need to change port of GeoServer in configuration file (jetty).

Comment: How to starts Geoserver as console/service?

Comment: Goto All Progrms --> Geoserver 2.*.* --> Click on 'Start Geoserver' if on Window machine. Please let me know if it's different OS.

Comment: Geoserver is started. That working fine with "localhost"

Comment: what happens if you open command line and run below command 'ping 92.20.100.12 '

Comment: I get this message: Request timed out.

Comment: That means server machine is not accessible to your machine. Both of the machines are not on the same n/w. Work with your n/w team to fix the issue. It's not geoserver issue. Try to use this command once to see if that works 'ping machinename(replace this with the geoserver machine name)'

Comment: "http://92.20.100.12:8080/geoserver/web/" not working on Windows Server therefore it's geoserver issue

Comment: replace the IP with hostname of the server machine. To find hostname, open command line again and type 'hostname' and enter. Run this command in windows server machine. Also confirm the IP of the machine is the same you are typing the browser using command ipconfig

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. with hostname and IP(result of ipconfig) working fine. but not working with "92.20.100.12".

Comment: No problem. Happy to share. It's not working with the mentioned iP because it's not the IP of the machine.

Comment: How to access geoserver of Windows Server? How to get wms service from that?

Comment: I will help you with that in a different question. Could you mark my response as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: yeah I mark your response :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100116/discussion-between-ch65-and-user3174598).

Comment: Sure, I ping you on the link that you asked. I never used it before but I follow the link.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the service launched, then try with this link:

http://92.20.100.12:8080/geoserver/web

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web" working fine but when I replace "localhost" with "92.20.100.12" not working.